# Permission denied to connect to Amazon EC2 using SSH at Windows 8

Tags: windows, git, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm starting using Amazon EC2 service. I have installed an Amazon Linux instance,  set the PEM file, opened the SSH ports and installed a GIT service.

My local environment it's Windows 8.

Through putty and WinSCP I can connect without problems. I have followed the docs and converted my PEM file to a PPK and everything works fine.
The problem is when I try to do a git push from my local machine. I always get a "permission denied (public key)" when I try to connect. I have made a ssh-add to PEM file using the git bash, generated a custom key trough the GIT Bash and added this key to the key pars at the EC2 Instance and nothing works...

If I try (using git bash) a ssh -i and specify the PEM file, I have a connection.

```
ssh -i c:/[PATH]/[PEM-FILE].pem ec2-user@[HOST].compute.amazonaws.com
```

If I try without -i, no connection.

```
$ ssh ec2-user@[HOST].compute.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here follows the trace with -vT command:

```
ssh -vT ec2-user@[HOST].compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to [HOST].compute.amazonaws.com [54.201.
110.48] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file [PATH]/Usuario/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file [PATH]/Usuario/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file [PATH]/Usuario/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '[HOST].compute.amazonaws.com' is known and ma
tches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in [PATH]/Usuario/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: [PATH]/Usuario/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: [PATH]/Usuario/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: [PATH]/Usuario/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So, there's a way to connect via SSH without the -i option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several tries, I found an article with some instructions here https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

I followed these steps: "After you have the home directory, and a .ssh folder under that, you want to open PuTTYgen and open the key (.ppk file) you have previously created. Once your key is open, you want to select Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key and save it to HOME.ssh\id_rsa. After you have the key at that location, Git bash will recognize the key and use it"

Comment: It's been long due, but this was the only answer that worked for me after lurk in SO for a while. Thanks for sharing the solution

Answer (score 3):

@Everton Menonca'a asnwer it great. It saved my day in fact. Just for the sake of more details, I am going to mention my case:

- Load the private key (generated by EC2) in your PuTTYgen, and from it, export OpenSSH key.
- Place the exported file in the home directory of all keys. In my case (windows) was `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh`
- Since I have multiple remotes I am connecting to using Bash, I updated my `config` file (under the same directory), by adding extra entry, to be like the following:

  ```
  Host bitbucket.org
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa1

  Host ec2-00-00-000-00.compute-1.amazonaws.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
  ```

That's all